# Closing a terminal window with an ssh session spawned from a function orphans the ssh rather than killing it

Tags: terminal, zsh

I recently started wrapping my ssh calls via a function in zsh, and I noticed that now if I close a terminal (Mac OS X / iTerm2) with an active ssh process, the ssh process doesn't die, but rather is orphaned (PPID=1). This subsequently hoses any tty applications (ie screen) on that ssh connection.

I have narrowed this problem down to zsh + functions. This is all it takes to reproduce:

```
zsh# function foo() { ssh user@host.com }
zsh# foo
--> Close the terminal window (via cmd-w)

zsh# ps ax -o pid,ppid,command | tee >(head -1) | grep -v grep | grep ssh
  PID  PPID COMMAND
29361     1 ssh user@host

zsh# kill 29361
--> everything is OK again.
```

I have verified this is a zsh issue since it doesn't reproduce in bash, and I've verified it isn't an ssh issue since it does reproduce with any command in zsh started from inside of a function.

I have reproduced this issue using zsh 4.2.x-5.x.x.

I don't understand the observed behavior, but would like to. I am not sure if this is expected or a bug in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also observe this behavior when you initially launch ZSH as

```
env -i TERM=$TERM zsh -f
```

i.e. without your custom configuration files being sourced?

An important option that controls ZSH's job control is `NO_HUP`.

See also [this discussion at superuser.com](https://superuser.com/q/552031/69517)